# Algebraic manipulation before doing implicit differentiation

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

So if I have the curve $ y = x $ and I do implicit differentiation, I get $ y' = 1$

But when I do implicit differentiation of $ \frac{y}{x} = 1$ I get $y' = \frac{y}{x}$

I guess on all points on $ y = x$ we get the same derivative but I still don't fully understand how to understand getting two different derivatives for the same curve (almost the same curve except for $ x \neq 0$)

More generally, for any given curve of the form $\frac{f(x,y)}{g(x,y)} = h(x,y)$ I am getting different answers when I do implicit differentiation of $ f(x,y) = h(x,y)g(x,y)$ vs the original form.

For instance, implicit differentiating $\frac{2x-y^3}{y+x^2} = 5x-4$ gives me $y' = \frac{-5x^4 - 2x^2 (5y+1)+2xy^3 + (2-5y)y}{3x^2y^2 + 2x+2y^3}$

Whereas implicit differentiating $2x - y^3 = (5x-4)(y+x^2)$ gives me $y' = \frac{-15x^2 + 8x -5y +2}{5x+3y^2-4}$

Which is the right way to go about it and more importantly what is going on ? How am I supposed to understand the different answers I get from implicit differentiation before vs after I perform some cross multiplications?

Comment: As you say, you get "almost the same curve", *not* the same curve. Note that if $x=y$, then $y' = \frac{y}{x} = \frac{x}{x} = 1$ for $x\neq 0$. So it is the same derivative where they are both defined.

Comment: Assuming the second example is computed correctly, you should be able to transform one into the other using the original equality as well.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin So, on the set of points which are common to both the curves (x = y and y/x = 1) , both derivative functions will give the same values but on points which are off both the curves, the derivative function can give wildly different answers and that's ok because those two curves are different and the purpose of the derivative function is to give you the right derivative "on" the curve ? Am I correct in my thinking?

Comment: On points that are off both curves, the derivative (i.e., the slope of the tangent to the curve at the point) does not exist. Plugging in points not on the curve into the expression is like trying to heat soup by hitting it with a hammer: sure, you can do that, but you'll just make a mess and won't accomplish what you thought you were trying to do.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin hahahahahaha thank you!! hahaha

Comment: If you integrate $y' = \frac{dy}{dx}$ you get $\ln(y) = ln(x) + C$, which becomes $y = Cx$.  In other words, the derivative you. get from your implicit derivative works for any straight line that crosses through the origin. This makes sense from the formula, since the multiplier will always have a differential of zero.  In any case,  it seems the explicit derivative generalizes to $y$ offsets, while the implicit derivative generalizes to scaling factors.